# Regex to find numbers in text that are encountered 3 or more times

Tags: regex

I need an regex to find numbers that were encountered 3 or more times in text.

```
some text 577
some 123 text
577 some text 
some 577 text 
some text 512
```

I need regex to match `577`

My last try was: `(?:\d+){3,}`

Comment: Please add sample data and your current regex attempt.

Comment: Though I initially voted to close, I now voted to re-open because of the adjustments to your post. On-topic: Does your application support backreferences? If so, you could try something like: [`\b(\d+)\b(?=(?:[\S\s]+\b\1\b){2})`](https://regex101.com/r/lG4aAx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\b([0-9]+)\b(?=(?:[\w\W]*?\b\1\b){2})
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/SkMgMU/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-
                               z, A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters
                               (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```